# Remove script type in WordPress for Nu HTML validation

Tags: php, wordpress

[Nu HTML warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0zz0.png)

I used the below code to replace the type attribute on the script tag.

```
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'clean_script_tag');

function clean_script_tag($input) {
  $input = str_replace("type='text/javascript' ", '', $input);
  return str_replace("'", '"', $input);
}
```

Most of them are got replaced but not the above mentioned one.

[Script type not removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N2KE.png)

Do I need to remove from the wp-admin?

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Never edit wp-admin files. I wouldn't give so much importance to it since it is just a warning. It just says it is not necessary, but it is not causing any issue

Comment: Hi @Yuri thank you for the reply. I found the location of the script. It is located in the **wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php**. If this is not going to be an issue I can leave as it is right?